# HTML How to change an object's position relative to another Image

Tags: html, css-float, centering

For my website I have an image showing a screen. Inside that screen I have moved an embeded youtube video inside that screen. So the embed is on top of the image. I can get the embeded video into the correct place using this:

```
<div style="position:relative"> 
  <img src="screen.png" />
  <div style="position:absolute; left:0px;top:0px;">    
    <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/qoSEzTpbxP4" width="310" height="210" allowfullscreen=true"></embed>           
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the entire thing to be centered, however if I surround this with  tags then obviously nothing centers because of the position; the embed stays 544 from the left of the window, not from the left of the image. Is there a way of making the embed move to match the images centered postion?

(NB: I'm aware that I should be using a seperate CSS doc for all styles, but I'm not interested in that right now, I just want to get it working then I might encapsulate styles into a seperate place later)

Comment: Couldn't you just use `screen.png` as the `background-image` for your `div` and set `text-align: center;` on the `div` to center the `embed`? [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/ikinav/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div style="margin: 0px auto; text-align: center; width: 500px; position: relative;"> 
  <img src="screen.png">
  <div style="position: absolute; z-index: 1; margin: 0px auto; text-align: center;">   
    <embed width="425" height="349" allowfullscreen="true&quot;" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/qoSEzTpbxP4">           
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. However the embed sits underneath the img with this code

Answer (score 0):

try this... good looking video frame !!!

```
<object height="360" width="580" id="video_MT6UDIruUkU" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
data="http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?enablejsapi=1&version=3">

    <param value="always" name="allowScriptAccess">
    <param value="transparent" name="wmode">
    <param value="video_id=MT6UDIruUkU&playerapiid=MT6UDIruUkU"
    name="flashvars">
    <param value="http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?enablejsapi=1&version=3"
    name="movie">

</object>

<div class="controlDiv play"></div>
```